# MS Word VB make check box control invisible when merge field is null

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, controls, mailmerge

I have a query that pulls information I need to use in a mail merge document to email to people for verification of information. There are 8 fields they need to verify, preferably with a check box control, but some of the fields contain  no information. I would like to make the check box next to merge fields that contain no data (or whatever I may need to write into the query to make this work) invisible.  If this could be accomplished easier in a completely different way, that would be fine too. Thank you.

Comment: Research the concept of `If` fields in Word documents. Note that this appears to be more targeted to an end-user scenario since, as far as I can tell, there's no proviso to include code in the document nor attach it later to code.

Comment: Thanks, Cindy.  I've tried some if statements but I'm not sure how to reference everything.  Right now I have: If txt_vehicle_8 = "Null" Then box_8.Visible = False
Else: box_8.Visible = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cindy said, this kind of thing is handled via field coding in the mailmerge main document, not via VB code. Such a field might be coded as:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD myCheck}<> "" "[ ]"}
```

or:

```
{IF«myCheck»<> "" "[ ]"}
```

where 'myCheck' is the field name and '[ ]' is the checkbox content control.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above examples are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.